# Elasticsearch - bump individual result to the top

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I'm working with Elasticsearch.  I have an array of documents, and I'm trying to sort documents by the property `price`, except that I'd like a particular document to be the first result no matter what.

The below is what I'm using as my `"sort"` array as my attempt to order documents by ID `1213`, and then all following documents ordered by price descending.

```json
[
  {
    "id": {
      "mode": "max",
      "order": "desc",
      "nested_filter": {
        "term": {
          "id": 1213
        }
      },
      "missing": "_last"
    }
  },
  {
    "price": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
]
```

This doesn't appear to be working, though—document 1213 doesn't appear first.  What am I doing wrong here?

As an example—the ideal returned result:

```
[{"id": 1213, "name": "Blue Sunglasses", "price": 12},
 {"id": 1000, "name": "Green Sunglasses", "price": 2},
 {"id": 1031, "name": "Purple Sunglasses", "price: 4},  
 {"id": 5923, "name": "Yellow Sunglasses, "price": 18}]
```

Instead, I get:

```
[{"id": 1000, "name": "Green Sunglasses", "price": 2},
 {"id": 1031, "name": "Purple Sunglasses", "price: 4},  
 {"id": 1213, "name": "Blue Sunglasses", "price": 12},
 {"id": 5923, "name": "Yellow Sunglasses, "price": 18}]
```

Comment: would be easier to understand if you post an example document and the way you would want the result to look ?

Comment: @keety This has been updated, thanks!

Comment: i'm confused is `{"id": 1000, "name": "Green Sunglasses", "price": 2}` a single document or a nested one withing a larger document  i ask because `nested filter` is applicable only in the latter scenario  and i don't think that is the case here

Comment: would it be possible to post the current query  in entirety ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already asked, what is the reason for the nested_filter?

There's many possible ways to do what you need.  Here is one possible way which fits with the simple requirements you mentioned so far:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "custom_filters_score" : {
            "query" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filters" : [
                {
                    "filter" : {
                        "term" : {
                            "id" : "1213"
                        }
                    },
                    "boost" : 2
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort" : [
        "_score",
        "price"
    ]
}
```

The assumption here is that your query is simple like the match_all query and does not affect the scores in anyway.  If you do have something more complicated for the queries, to not affect the scores, you can try wrapping with a constant_score query.  But ideally you get the document set you want where all the documents have the same score and then [custom_filters_score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-custom-filters-score-query.html) will boost the score of the document you want.  You can do this for any number of documents adding further filters or if the documents are equal, use a terms filter.  In the end the sort by the score and then the price.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it achieves the goal without requiring scripts to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to use `function_score` to modify score of each doc.

```
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "id": "1213"
                  }
               },
               "weight": 1
            },
            {
               "script_score": {
                  "script": "(1 / doc['price'].value)"
               }
            }
         ],
         "score_mode": "sum",
         "boost_mode" : "replace",
         "query" : {
             //YOUR QUERY GOES HERE
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Explanation:

```
{
   "script_score": {
        "script": "(1 / doc['price'].value)"
    }
}
```

Compute score based on **price** and give a value < 1. The higher the price the smaller the score (ascending). If you want to switch to descending then just  replace it with
`"script": "(1 - (1 / doc['price'].value))"`

```
{
   "filter": {
        term": {
           "id": "1213"
        }
    },
    "weight": 1
 }
```

This will give any docs with `"id" = 1213` an extra 1 score. The total score at the end will be the sum of those 2 functions.

Comment: I _want_ the prices to be out of order; I want id `1213` on top, is the issue.  Reordering the sort clauses would sort by price first and id second, which is not what I want.